# Find the first & last timestamp for each day from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

Hope someone can help - I have an array of half-hourly energy meter readings and need to loop through and extract the first and last meter reading each day using the timestamps. I have the data in the following formats, either timestamp/string or unix/milliseconds  - its a large array covering several months.

```
[ 
 [ '2018-09-10 22:51:53', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-10 23:21:55', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-10 23:51:56', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-11 00:21:57', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-11 00:51:59', 258.707 ] 
]
```

OR

```
[ 
 [ 1536623513000, 258.707 ],
 [ 1536625315000, 258.707 ],
 [ 1536627116000, 258.707 ],
 [ 1536628917000, 258.707 ],
 [ 1536630719000, 258.707 ] 
]
```

Is there a moment function or alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can filter the array so it only contains a single day, then simply get the first and last element.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this approach would also work but still requires a filter test to identify the first or last timestamp each day  - any thoughts how to do this?

Comment: After filtering, sort the array by date, then grab first and last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Group elements by date
2. Find min and max for each collection of date

```js
var demo = [ 
 [ '2018-09-10 22:51:53', 258.3 ],
 [ '2018-09-10 23:21:55', 258.2 ],
 [ '2018-09-10 23:51:56', 258.5 ],
 [ '2018-09-11 00:21:57', 258.7027 ],
 [ '2018-09-11 00:51:59', 251.707 ] 
];


let grouped_items = _.groupBy(demo, function(b) {
  return moment(b[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
});

  Object.keys(grouped_items).forEach(function(item) {
    grouped_items[item] = findMinMax( grouped_items[item]);
});


function findMinMax(item){
   var res = {min: item[0][1], max:item[0][1]};
  
  item.forEach(function(val) {
    res.min = val[1] < res.min ? val[1] :res.min;
    res.max = val[1] > res.max ? val[1] :res.max;
});
  
  return res;
}

console.log(grouped_items);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Alessio, this solution is perfect for my needs and has allowed me to extract all the data I require - cheers!

Comment: if you think that the answer is correct, you can accept it, maybe it can be useful to other users.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

Converted the code sample from PHP into JavaScript - I fooled myself previously.

```
var result = {}, item, stamp, reading;
while(data.length)
{
  // we do not care about the order of the items
  item = data.pop();
  stamp = item[0];
  reading = item[1];

  // get the date only, strip the time
  if(typeof stamp !== 'number') stamp = stamp.substr(0, 10);
  else stamp = (new Date(stamp)).toISOString().substr(0, 10);

  item = result[stamp];
  if(item)
  {
    if(reading < item[0]) item[0] = reading;
    else if(reading > item[1]) item[1] = reading;
  }
  // this date was not seen before
  else result[stamp] = [reading, reading]; // MIN and MAX are the same
}
```

For each item from the original array - you create a bucket for the given date and update the MIN and MAX values for this date.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention PHP *anywhere*, as far as I can see?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I mentioned in my comment:

1. filter the array to look at each day individually
2. sort the elements of each day
3. grab the day array's first and last element

Code example:

```js
const data = [
  ['2018-09-10 22:51:53', 258.707],
  ['2018-09-10 23:21:55', 259.707],
  ['2018-09-10 23:51:56', 259.907],
  ['2018-09-11 00:21:57', 260.101],
  ['2018-09-11 00:51:59', 260.102]
];

const monthfilter = month => datestring => new Date(datestring[0]).getMonth() === month;
const datefilter = date => datestring => new Date(datestring[0]).getDate() === date;

// filter by month first so sorting is optimized
for (var month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
  var monthdata = data.filter(monthfilter(month)).sort((a, b) => a > b);
  // go through each day of the month
  for (var date = 1; date <= 30; date++) { // 30 days is just for september example!
    // grab day data
    var tmp = monthdata.filter(datefilter(date));
    if (tmp.length === 0) continue;
    print(tmp[0][0], tmp[0][1], tmp.pop()[1]);
  }
}

function print(datestring, first, last) {
  var date = new Date(datestring).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  console.log(`${date}: ${first} - ${last}\n`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can achieve this is to sort the array, and then grab the first and last index.

for example

```
sort($your_array);
$first_reading=$your_array[0];
$last_index=count($your_array)-1;
$last_reading=$your_array[$last_index];
```

What happens here is that it first sorts the array from low (first reading) to high (last reading) with the function sort), more info about it can be found here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

then you get the last element in the array with the function count, which will count how many elements are in an array. Make sure you subtract 1 from that count, because the index of the array starts at 0 (while the count starts at 1).

edit: more array sorting functions can be found here:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php
in case you want to sort with keys or something.

Comment: Thanks hortig, I'm not familar with PHP but I'm sure this could be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the nested array structure is best for handling this kind of data.  Would it be feasible to use objects inside the array instead, to associate the dates with a property that you can filter by?

If you want to use the nested arrays, I think you first have to address converting the date and time into a format that can be easily evaluated with comparison operators.  You can loop over each entry in the array and return the date as the day of the month (so all entries on 2018-09-10 would return the number 10, and so on)  and the time as a number of milliseconds (since January 1st 1970).  So like this:

```
    var dates = [ 
 [ '2018-09-10 22:51:53', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-10 23:21:55', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-10 23:51:56', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-11 00:21:57', 258.707 ],
 [ '2018-09-11 00:51:59', 258.707 ] 
]

dates.forEach(day => {
              var date = new Date(day[0]);
              var newDay = date.getDate();
              var newTime = date.getTime()
              console.log(newDay);
              console.log(newTime);
          });
```

Comment: Hi Eric, the data is obtained in JSON so started off in object format, I extracted into an array for use elsewhere but think you're right this would be an easier approach - thanks.

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the moment().dayOfYear() function (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day-of-year/), to check which day the date belongs to, then you could compare the valueOf() (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) to see which are the first and the last ones.

If your dates span multiple years, you could additionally check for the year.

Comment: Thanks WhiteMaple - i like this idea think it could work - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked so I guess it is already solved, anyway this is my workaround just need to form it as JSON Array, if not use [0] instead .date:

```
  demo.find(element=>
    new Date(element.date).getTime() === Math.min(...demo
   .map(value=> new Date(value.date).getTime()
  ))
)
```

**JSFiddle**
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83kcembw/)